# What Is the Origin of the Word "Sherpa"?

Tags: etymology

Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, Subscription-only says:

> **Sherpa** `n.` a Himalayan person who is often employed to guide people through mountains and carry their equipment
>
> **Word Origin**
>
> **Date:** 1800-1900
> **Language:** Tibetan
> **Origin:** *sherpa* 'someone who lives in an eastern country'

Online Etymology Dictionary (http://www.etymonline.com) also says:

> **Sherpa** 1847, from Tibetan, literally "dweller in an eastern country."

However the word itself sounds very much Persian to me, in which *sher* means *lion* and *pa* means *foot/leg*, and the combination altogether (similar to other two-word combinations in the language) can indicate someone who has strong legs and feet that makes it easy for them to climb up the mountains.

I was talking to another linguist recently and they had the same opinion on the word, and that encouraged me to look further more into the word. As I can see, Tibetan is not even something related to Persian or any other Indo-European languages, and belongs to Tibetic (Sino-Tibetan) languages.

Is there any further information on the origin of this word?

Comment: In the absence of more convincing evidence, a false-friend explanation would seem more likely. //// In fact, Josh's new explanation seems compelling. It would make a good answer if referenced.

Comment: I think it is relevant that many Tibetans have the last name 'Sherpa', so it is conceivable that, while all these well-researched answers explain the etymology of the word 'sherpa', it could be that the mountaineers are given the class label 'sherpa' is because  many of them (but not all) have that as their family name, and Westerners just called them as a whole 'sherpas'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/178018?redirectedFrom=sherpa#eid)* confirms that it is from Tibetan *sharpa*, inhabitant of an eastern country. The other forms listed are *Serpa, Sharpa* and the earliest forms recorded are *Serpa* and *Sérpá* from 1847.

> 1847     B. H. Hodgson in *Jrnl. Asiatic Soc. Bengal* XVI. 1237   Cis-Himálayan Bhotias vel Tibetans, called..**Serpa**, &c. 
> 1847     B. H. Hodgson in *Jrnl. Asiatic Soc. Bengal* XVI. 1238   The sub-Himálayan races..inhabit all the central and temperate parts of these mountains, the juxta nivean or nethermost tracts being left to the Rongbo vel **Sérpá**.

The following excerpt is from an article titled "Sherpa History" from the official site of *Tapting* (a village development committee in Nepal) and explains the origin of *sherpa* with historical references and citations from ethnologists.

> - Sherpa is an easterner indigenous people, live in the eastern part of Nepal. The word Sherpa is combination of two words – "Shyar" (East) and "Pa" (people) "People of the East" and the words are coined from the Tibetan language.
> - The word 'Sherpa' means easterner as it is addressed to the present day Sherpa. It is not clear how this term came to be associated with this particular group
> - Previously they were not addressed by the word 'Sherpa'. But it is not clear in what circumstances this term came to be associated with this particular group from the Tibetan point of view, *Sherpas* dwelling in the highlands of Nepal are southerners rather than are easterners, though there is the tradition that before their migration to their present habitat they had settled in eastern Tibet *(Haimendorf 1964,1984)*
> - In this context, some Sherpas came to the conclusion that they address 'nubripa', western, for the same type of culture group whose habitat is western part of Nepal. Similarly, the term Sherpa is used for the "eastern inhabitants of Nepal".
> - Another group opined that the term indicates" man from rising sun area". Therefore, they were addressed Sherpa. But it is so why the other ethnic groups of Eastern Nepal is not addressed by the term "Sherpa".
> - According to reincarnated Lama of Tengboche monastry, the first man came to *Khumbu* from *Kham Salmo-Gang* (east of Tibet) whose clan was called *Timi* (*Thimi*), incarnated from the god *Wosal* and his name was *pajzin*. After he returned back to Tibet the people asked him where he came from he replied "the east part of Kham" That is how the name Sherpa, easterner came into being *(Kunuwar,1989)*
> - But some Sherpas of Solu are not in favor of this opinion. According to them, the word Sherpa is of very late origin.
> - It has come to know on the basis of different literatures cited above that Sherpas were migrated to Nepal from the Kham region of Tibet 5 to6 hundred years back.
> - It is presumed that the group of people migrated out from Kham region, east of Tibet, was called as " Shyar Khamba" (People who came from eastern Kham) and the place where the migrant people started to settle was called " Syar Khumbu". As the time passed the " Shyar Khamba", inhabitants of shyar Khumbu, were called as Sherpa.
>
> <sub>http://tapting.org/sherpa-history/</sub>

---

However, I did some research regarding your theory about *sher* being lion in *sherpa* and I could find some hints related to *Thakali* language (*Thakali* is one of the ethnolinguistic groups in Nepal along with *Sherpa* and these two groups share the same region in Nepal). <sup>(see [map](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Nepal_ethnic_groups.png))</sup>.

The first reference I could find is about the Thakali clan *Sercan* which has a lion on their emblem; and the root of the word is mentioned as *ser-* which suggests that it might mean lion. (from the book *Himalayan Anthropology: The Indo-Tibetan Interface*
edited by James F. Fisher):

> However, one cannot fail to compare the Thakali Sercan (emblem: the white lion of the glaciers) with the Sherpa Serwa, especially as *-can* is a suffix. The accepted etymology of *Sherpa* is Tibetan *shar* [east] (Snellgrove 1957:215; Oppitz 1968:49), but one suspects at the very least contamination with the root *Ser-*; spoken Nepali has only one sibilant phoneme. 
> <sub>*Note:* *Snellgrove* is a tibetologist and *Oppitz* is an ethnologist.</sub>

I continued my research by focusing on the term *Sercan* and I could find another form of the term which is *Shercan*. It is one of the four *Thakali* clans and the clan protector is mentioned as the *white lion of the glaciers*. (from the publication *Ritual practice and group maintenance in the Thakali of central Nepal* by Andrew E. Manzardo)

[image]

Then, I could finally find a source that actually says *sher* means lion in *Thakali* language. Here is the relevant excerpt from the book *The Thakali: a Himalayan ethnography* by Michael Vinding:

> Since the Nepali clan names were introduced in the present century, it is somewhat surprising that the Tamang Thakali do not know their meaning. The account of the *Cyogi* clan, the *Cyogi Rhab*, written in the Devanagari script, renders the clan names as *gaucan, tulacan, syercan* and *battacan*. The ending *-can* may be an attempt by the names inventor(s) to connect the *Tamang Thakali* with the *Thakuri* clan *Chand*. *Gau* means 'cow' and may be related with *gaucan* clan god. ***Sher* means 'lion' and appears related with the *Shercan* clan god.** *Bhatt_* may mean 'exchange' and may be indirectly connected with the *Bhattacan* clan god. The meaning of *tula* is a puzzle.

On the other hand, lion is *senggi* in Sherpa language (from *Sherpa-English English-Sherpa Dictionary* by Nicolas Tournadre, Lhakpa Norbu Sherpa, Gyurme Chodrak & Guillaume Oisel):

[image]
[image]

Oh! Let's not forget *pa*. This Tibetan affix strongly suggests that it is related to people in the word *sherpa*, although it is a very versatile affix that can be used in a variety of ways. The below excerpt is the definition of *pa* from *A Tibetan-English Dictionary with special reference to the prevailing dialects* By H. A. Jäschke:

> པ pa, an affix, or so-called article, the
> same as ba (q.v.) which, when attached to the roots of verbs, gives them the signification of nouns, or, in other words is the sign of the infinitive and the participle; in the language of common life, however, it is frq. used for the finite tense, and for par; affixed to the names of things, it denotes the person that deals with the thing (*rtá-pa* horseman, *čú-pa* water-carrier); combined with names of places, it designates the inhabitant (bód-pa inhabitant of Tibet); with numerals, it either forms the ordinal number (*ynyis-pa* the second), or it implies a counting, measuring, containing *(bú-mo lo-ynyis-pa* a girl counting two years, i. e. a girl of two years; *Kru-gánpa* measuring one cubit; *súm-cu-pa* containing thirty viz. letters, like the Tibetan alphabet); frq. it has no particular signification (*rkéd-pa* etc. etc.), or it serves to distinguish different meanings (*rkan* marrow, *rkán-pa* foot) or dialects (*ká-ba* B., *ka* W. snow); *pa dan* with a verb, v. *dan* 4; in certain expressions it stands, it would seem, incorr. inst. of *pai*: *ysó-ba rig-pa* science of medicine, *grub-pa lus* structure of the body, *dám-pa čos* holy doctrine (of Buddha).

In conclusion, the accepted etymology of *sherpa* is Tibetan *sher* (east) and *pa* (people or inhabitant) but there is a good evidence that *sher* might be related to lion based on the above findings.

Answer (score 7):

The following source provides futher information on the term which don't actually support your assumption of the origin from persian Sher (lion) pa (leg/foot):

> - Although westerners pronounce it "Sher-pa" the native Sherpa pronunciation is "Shar-wa."
> - Shar means "east" --   wa means "person" --- in Sherpa and Tibetan language.

[image]In Tibetan script, the word "Shar-wa" is spelled like this.

> - The word "Sharwa" is also a relatively recent identifier.  As the eminent Nepali anthropologist Dor Bahadur Bista remarks in his extensive descriptions of Nepal's many ethnic and tribal groups "Peoples of Nepal" (Ratna Pustak, Kathmandu, 1967):
> - "Through the course of time the name Sherpa has gained so much currency that it almost acts as a tribal name, and it does in fact define a specific group of people.  Before Sherpas were so highly publicized by mountaineering expeditions, they introduced themselves to other societies as "Shar Khombo" - i.e., the inhabitants of Shar-Khumbu. " (

From: [Sherpa History and Facts](http://www.sherpakyidug.org/sherpa/sherpa_facts.asp)

Comment: Would that be another example of an exonym used for a group of people based on which subdivision of that people was encountered first?